# Melhor opção para armazenar (chave, chave e valor) em C#?

Tags: c#, dicionário

Estou trabalhando em uma ferramenta onde o usuário insere uma informação e com base em alguns cálculos no valor inserido ele retorna uma descrição de valor de fixo.
Exemplo:
O usuário insere o valor 101.
Ele valor será calculado baseados em algumas regras.
Esse valor por exemplo se encaixa no Grupo A o resultado final após o calculo é 3 (Podemos ter diversos grupos A, B, C, D, E, F, G e por ai vai...), e para cada grupo tenho alguma valores já pre-definidos.
Grupo A:
0 = definição inapropriada
1 = aceita todo tipo de requisição
2 = aguardando validação
3 = status ok

Eu estava armazenando esses Valores em Dictionary.
Existe alguma solução mais simples para eu pegar esses caras de forma dinâmica ou alimentar o Dictionary dinamicamente para depois consumi-lo ?

Pensei em guardar em um arquivo .txt e montar o dicionario.
arquivo.txt
A;0;Status Inicial
A;1;Falha de inicialização
A;2;Falha ao encerrar
A;3;Status OK
Z;10;Erro na memória
Z;24;Tentativa incorreta
Z;54;Corrompido
Z;55;Status indefinido

Answer (score 0):

O dicionário é a melhor opção para sua necessidade quando se tem muitos dados, ele calcula o HASH (que é uma operação rápida, proporcional ao tamanho do dado), e armazena em uma linked list (ligada por ponteiros) os ítens em que houver colisão de HASH.

Basicamente são três operações:

- Cálculo de Hash (rápido, proporcional ao tamanho do dado)
- Consulta numa tabela de HASH (rápido, indexação de array)
- Consulta linear numa lista ligada (a parte menos rápida)

Fique atento se utilizar valores de ponto flutuante como chave (pois são calculados), o dicionário só retornará correspondências exatas.

Quanto à inicialização do dicionário, pode fazer estaticamente no código ou deserializar de um arquivo (txt, csv, xml, json, yaml, ini, binário, etc...)

Existe também a possibilidade de utilizar um banco de dados estático, onde, tendo as chaves, você obtém a mensagem com uma consulta SQL comum. O Sqlite tem código fonte aberto e muitos desenvolvedores o utilizam (ex.: chrome/chromium).

Para poucos dados é melhor fazer um switch mesmo, a consulta acaba sendo mais eficiente que computar HASHs, ou consultar banco de dados, mas faça seus testes.

Comment: Legal Edney,  
Hoje estou populando na unha o dictionary.  
Tem alguma forma de eu fazer isso dinamicamente ?  
Pois esse dictionary pra ser criado ele Precisa do Grupo depois da chave e valor.
Ou seja estou criando 1 dicionario para cada grupo.  
Queria ter apenas um dicionário e após o calculo e identificar o grupo eu montava esse dicionário, com base em algum arquivo de texto ou json ou alguma outra coisa.  
Não sei como proceder.

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio dificil de entender mas eu chuto (com base no que você escreveu) que você precisa de um : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, object>>. Então pode usar com: valores[i][j]. Edita sua questão e coloque mais detalhes, senão fica dificil...

Comment: Também, você pode usar um Struct como chave (com o grupo e valor), assim terá somente um dicionário. Recomendado você tornar o Struct imutável para usar como chave de dicionário (com campos privados e passar os parâmetros no construtor).

Comment: Editei a questão, pensei em, guardar em um txt todos os detalhes das mensagens e os grupos e depois montar no dicionario  Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>

Comment: Se for muitos dados (mas não muitíssimos) pode usar um Sqlite, não depende de servidor, e é bem eficiente.